# Why does Stack Exchange allow VPN logins?

Tags: support

Most sites like Alldebrid, Wikipedia, etc. ban [VPN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) logins. By "banning" I mean that the site doesn't open up all of its features to users who come in from a VPN.

So why does Stack Exchange still allow VPN logins?

Comment: And why not? Can you elaborate on the downsides of allowing VPN?

Answer (score 7):

I assume you mean *public* VPNs, since a whole lot of us use VPNs for work...

Anyway, the answer is "because it doesn't matter". To the extent that we use network-based blocking to reduce abuse, we use it for *all* networks - after all, abusing the site from your desk at work isn't somehow less abusive than doing it from a coffee shop over a VPN.

If someone wants to pay money for a different IP that anyone else with money can abuse and get banned with no recourse, that's on them. Same with Tor and other proxies - your access is perpetually at the mercy of whoever else is using them, and vice-versa.